# Constructor overloading same arguments

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

Suppose I have class with 2 fields: x and y, of type `double`. Is it possible to define 2 constructors so  constructor1 will create object setting its `x` property to what parameter in constructor tell and `y` to default and constructor2 vice versa?

```
public class Test {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Test(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Test(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

I'm trying something like that and I know that it wont work because of overloading rules

Comment: You can do it, but you'll need some second parameter to distinguish the overloads. At that point, you might just want to make the two parameters `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't do that. Typically you'd do something like:

```
private Test(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public static Test fromX(int x) {
    return new Test(x, 0);
}

public static Test fromY(int y) {
    return new Test(0, y);
}
```

You might want to consider that pattern (public static factory methods which in turn call private constructors) even when you *don't* have overloading issues - it makes it clear what the meaning of the value you're passing is meant to be.

Answer (score 3):

No, You cannot have two methods or constructors with the same signature.  What you can do is have named static factories.

```
public class Test {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    private Test(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static Test x(int x) { return new Test(x, 0); }
    public static Test y(int y) { return new Test(0, y); }
}

Test x1 = Test.x(1);
Test y2 = Test.y(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, x and y have identical types, so both constructors would have the same type signature and the method resolution is based on parameter type, not name; the compiler has no way of differentiation.

The compiler looks for "Test.Test(int)" regardless of what the name of the parameter is.

The language would need additional feature added, such as named parameters, to do what you want.

If Java ever gets a syntax like C# for property initialization, you'll be able to use that idiom, using a default no-args constructor.

Besides the alternatives of using explicit factory methods, you could pass in a HashMap for your parameters.

```
 public Test(HashMap<string,int> args) {
      if(args.containsKey("x"))
         x = args.get("x");
      if(args.containsKey("y"))
         y = args.get("y");
 }
```

But static factory methods are cleaner for most cases. If you need much more, you may need to consider why you need such an idiom in the first place, and revise your class design.